# NSMutableArray of UIButton

Tags: ios

I have an NSMutableArray of buttons. When one of the buttons is pressed, I change it to a darker color. But I also want to change the background color of the other buttons so none of the previously pressed keep the darker color.

```
 for(UIButton* u in menuButtons)
 {
        NSLog(@"test");
        [u setBackgroundColor:[self byteColor:141.0 g:52.0 b:42.0] ];
 }
```

But it doesn't even go into this loop. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: In the same class @interface MessagesViewController : UIViewController
{    
    NSMutableArray * menuButtons;

Oh, I am getting null for NSLog(@"%@", menuButtons)

Comment: how you have added button in menuButtons??

Comment: rid- It should contain 3 buttons. Which are currently drawn on the screen.
Armaan- when the view loads, with [menuButtons addObject:button];

Comment: Oh, found the problem. I hadn't initialized the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it doesn't even go into this loop**  means the buttons are not added properly to the array.Initialize the array and add the outlets first properly and the method will work